# One way ANOVA. One estimator yields larger value under alternative hypothesis

Tags: anova

I am reading the topic on One way ANOVA from the text - Introductory Statistics by Sheldon Ross. To explain the concept of ANOVA, the author has found estimates of $\sigma^2$ using two different approaches and deduced that when the sample means are not equal, the variance found out from the second method is larger in value **( text shown in red in the second image)**.

How do I prove this is true? Hints quite appreciated. Thank you!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at at some specific fictitious data
to illustrate the two estimates of $\sigma^2 = 16,$
the common variance of the $k=3$ levels of a factor
in a balanced design with $r = 30$ replications
in each of the three groups.

**Data and summaries.**

```
set.seed(2022)
x1 = rnorm(30, 50, 4)
a1 = mean(x1);  v1 = var(x1)
x2 = rnorm(30, 60, 4)
a2 = mean(x2);  v2 = var(x2)
x3 = rnorm(30, 80, 4)
a3 = mean(x3);  v3 = var(x3)
```

The three group means are estimated as:

```
a1;  a2;  a3
[1] 49.53628
[1] 55.43423
[1] 61.49257
```

And the three group variances as:

```
v1;  v2;  v3
[1] 13.71546
[1] 11.1894
[1] 22.56334
```

Here are separate boxplots of the data in the the
three groups:

```
x = c(x1, x2, x3)
g = as.factor(rep(1:3, each=30)) # see Note (2)
boxplot(x~g, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

**Two variance estimates for ANOVA.**

Ross's *second* estimator of $\sigma^2$ is sometimes
called $S_w^2,$ for 'variance within groups'.
[It is analogous to the pooled variance $S_p^2$ in a two-sample t test.] It can be found by
averaging the three group variances. With only 45 observations altogether, we can't expect a wonderfully accurate estimate of $\sigma^2,$ but
is the best estimate available from our data.
It is the best estimate whether or not the three
group means are equal.

```
v.w = mean(c(v1,v2,v3));  v.w
[1] 15.82273
```

Ross's first variance estimate is based on the three group
means. If $H_0$ were true so that $\mu_1 = \mu_2 = \mu_3 = \mu,$ then the three group population means would be
a sample from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma/\sqrt{30}),$ so that the variance of the three means
should estimate $\sigma^2/30.$ Thus, $r=30$ times the variance of the three means would also estimate
$\sigma^2.$  This possibly inflated estimate is sometimes called
$S_a^2$ for the variance among groups. For our data, it is computed in R as:

```
30 * var(c(a1, a2, a3))
[1] 7917.119
```

One can show that $$F = S_a^2/S_w^2
 \sim\mathsf{F}(k-1 = 2,\; k(n-1) = 3(29)=87),$$
Snedecor's F-distribution with 2 and 87 degrees of freedom.

**ANOVA table.** It is customary to display the
computations for an analysis of variance in a table
such as the one for our fictitious data below (slightly abridged):

```
anova(lm(x~g))

Analysis of Variance Table

Response: x
          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
 g         2 15834.2  7917.1  500.36 < 2.2e-16 
Residuals 87  1376.6    15.8
```

In the column headed `Mean Sq` you can recoginze
$S_a^2 = 7917.119$ and $S_2^2 = 15.82273$ from above (slightly rounded to save space).

Because $S_a^2$ is inflated by differing means
to be so much larger than $S_w^2,$ the F-statistic
is very large and the P-value is near $0.$

---

*Notes:* (1) In condensed format here are
computations for fictitious data where the population means are equal, so that $S_a^2$ is not
inflated, and the null hypothesis is not rejected.

```
set.seed(114)
y1 = rnorm(30, 60, 4)
a1 = mean(y1);  v1 = var(y1)
y2 = rnorm(30, 60, 4)
a2 = mean(y2);  v2 = var(y2)
y3 = rnorm(30, 60, 4)
a3 = mean(y3);  v3 = var(y3)

v.w = mean(c(v1,v2,v3));  v.w
[1] 16.73631

v.a = 30 * var(c(a1, a2, a3));  v.a
[1] 8.239104
```

[image]

```
y = c(y1, y2, y3)
g = as.factor(rep(1:3, each=30))
anova(lm(y~g))

Analysis of Variance Table

Response: y
          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
g          2   16.48  8.2391  0.4923 0.6129
Residuals 87 1456.06 16.7363
```

(2) It is **crucial** to declare `g` as a 'factor' variable, otherwise R will do a regression instead of an ANOVA.

(3) This Answer is for a balanced design with equal numbers of replications in each group. Formulas for an unbalanced design are a bit messier.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You mentioned $S_a^2$ as the inflated variance. I am sorry if I missed something, but how do we know that this is indeed inflated when the population means are not equal? Is there mathematical reasoning to this?

Comment: Yes, one can show that the expected value of MS(Factor) is the sum of $\sigma^2$ and a quadratic form involving the $\mu$s.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for mentioning that. most of the books I read did not explicitly mention this. Do you have any recommendation wherein I could read this proof in detail? Thanks again!

Comment: Almost any text on design of experiments. Also [this link](http://langcog.stanford.edu/expts/MLL/Coursework/Statistical%20Methods%20(Psych.%20252)/Handouts:Slideshows/Week%207/07ho11EMS.pdf) may be helpful. Sect. 1.